# Magento: Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id) not working

Tags: magento

Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id) is not working (no data is loaded, and getId() is empty).

but if I do this:

```
     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
     foreach($collection as $category) {
         if($category->getId() == $id) {
             echo "it has been founnnd!!!";

         }
     }
```

it works?

I should mention I am running this code through cli with phpunit tests so its bootstrapped.  My guess is that there might be an issue with scope?

Answer (score 15):

I think the issue must be with your unit tests or somewhere else.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
  ->setStoreId($store_id)
  ->load($id);
```

works perfectly fine for me, no matter whether I use PHP's `apache`, `apache2handler`, `cgi`, `cgi-fcgi` or `cli` SAPI and no matter which Magento version (CE 1.3, 1.5, 1.6 and EE 1.11) I've tried.

Answer (score 5):

What I noticed (yes, after 3 years) is that:

1) Category will not load if you have category flat tables enabled and indexes are not up to date

2) Category will not load if it's not into "Default Category"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe flat category tables were used and index not up to date. See this [article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_flat_collection_chaos) from alan storm.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will definitely works,

```
$categoryId = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load($categoryId);
```